# Build an array from PHP and use smarty tags to display results in accordion

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, smarty

I am trying to pull and categorize data in a jQuery accordion. I managed to get this to work at a very basic level by building a PHP array. The table 'charts_groups' contains level 1 categories, and the code (successfully) pulls all the right elements that fall under the categories by matching the element IDs with level 1 group IDs.

Now, because my population has grown, I want to add subcategories (accordion within an accordion). So I have created a third database 'chart_subgroups', and I want build the parent / child relationships in exactly the same way. So: pseudo code is as follows:

List all categories in Db1 (charts_groups), then list all subcategories in Db2 (chart_subgroups) that fall under Db1, then list all elements in Db3 ('charts') that fall under Db2 subcategories.

Could you guys let me know what's wrong with the script below? Thank you so much for your help!

**This stuff should generate the array:**

```
    $groups_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `charts_groups`", $app->db());
    $chart_groups = array();           

        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($groups_result)) {

                while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($charts_result)) {
                       $subgroup_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `charts_subgroups` WHERE Sub_Group = {$row1['ID']}", $app->db());
                       $subgroup_data = array();                              
                          while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($charts_result)) {                       
                                 $charts_result = mysql_query("SELECT ID, Name, Type  FROM `charts` WHERE GroupId = {$row2['ID']}", $app->db());
                                 $chart_data = array();                                                     
                                 $chart_data[] = $row3;
                                 }                              
                        $subgroup_data[] = $row2;
                        } 
            $row2['subcategories'] = $subgroup_data;           
            $row3['chart_data'] = $chart_data;
            $chart_groups[] = $row1;
        }
```

Comment: What is actually displayed when you run your code? Hard to debug it without knowing what's going on. Also, before any one else says it, you should abandon mysql calls in favor of pdo() or mysqli().

Comment: Hello the_pete, thank you for your reply. The code above does not need to be debugged as it works. It correctly lists all categories in database 'charts_groups' and then matches all elements in 'charts' that have a 'GroupID' matching the 'ID' of the parent category. What I need to do is to insert subcategories between the two. So list category, then subcategories within category, then match elements to the subgroup

Comment: the_pete I have now amended my question. I am now showing the code that is not working, so this is now very much a debugging question and should be easier to work out what it is I am trying to do.

Comment: What does `$chart_groups` look like after your while loop finishes?